# Rails model associations and controllers/routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup an association where I have Shows that are associated to Cities.

The relationship is many shows to one city.

I would like to create new shows by city

Like such:
mysite.com/cities/1/shows/new

I have setup the models already so that:

```
Shows
Belongs_to :city

City
Has_many :shows
```

How do I setup my City controller with a  new shows action? How to I setup my routes.rb for this?

**I've figured it out**

In routes.rb

```
resources :cities do
  resources :shows
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a rule such as :

match /cities/:id/shows/new => "shows#new"

And after, in your new action in the controller shows, you could preload the city_id to be params[:id], something as

```
def new
    @show = Show.new(:city_id => params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this helps me with the controller/action part of the question.